# Issue with import pandas error using mod_wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask, mod-wsgi

I devlopped a flask app in which I use pandas.
When I start the python environment using
Source myenv/bin/activate
And run.py
=> everything is ok and the app run normally
But when I try to deploy the app using mod_wsgi it crushes with this importing pandas error
Pandas/**init**.py line 13
Missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}:{e}")
Am I missing something ?
I use the standard mod_wsgi config that is working for with another app that doesn't use pandas
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem:
It was due to python 2 used to compile mod_wsgi
I changed that to python 3
Now everything is working fine